# Modifying a value inside an enum while matching

Tags: enums, pattern-matching, rust

Is it possible to directly modify a value embedded inside an enum?

The following fails with `` error: cannot borrow immutable anonymous field `a.0` as mutable ``, even though I used `ref mut`.

```
enum Foo {
    Bar(usize),
}

fn main() {
    let a = Foo::Bar(10);

    match a {
        Foo::Bar(ref mut val) => *val = 33,
    }
    match a {
        Foo::Bar(val) => println!("{}", val), // should print 33
    }
}
```

That's not a huge problem because I can do the following as a work-around:

```
match a {
    Foo::Bar(val) => a = Foo::Bar(33),
}
```

But is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the binding to `a` mutable.

```
enum Foo {
    Bar(usize),
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Foo::Bar(10);

    match a {
        Foo::Bar(ref mut val) => *val = 33,
    }
    match a {
        Foo::Bar(val) => println!("{}", val), // 33
    }
}
```